# "npx expo-doctor" command fails in expo SDK 48

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am using expo SDK 48(Managed workflow). I always get an error while running following command

```
npx expo-doctor
```

It gives the following log:

```
npx expo-doctor
✔ Validating global prerequisites versions passed
✔ Checking for incompatible packages passed
✔ Checking for conflicting global packages in project passed
✖ Verifying prebuild support package versions are compatible failed
Issues:
  Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
  Found invalid:
    @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
    @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
    @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
    (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Advice:
  • Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.
✔ Checking dependency versions for compatibility with the installed Expo SDK passed
✔ Validating Expo Config passed
✔ Checking package.json for common issues passed

✖ Found one or more possible issues with the project. See above logs for issues and advice to resolve.
```

How can i solve this. I can build my app successfully though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

This worked for me, added a resolution in package.json :

```
  "resolutions": {
        "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
        "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0",
        "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.1.0"
    },
```

Comment: Did you do anything else afterward? Just adding it does not work for me

Comment: @Michael delete your node_modules folder and run yarn , after adding the resolutions in package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm ls @expo/config-plugins`
In my case it produced the following result

```
capmon-mobile@1.0.0 /home/mick/projects/capmon-mobile
├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1
├─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.0.1
│ ├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
│ └─┬ @expo/config@8.0.2
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
├─┬ eas-cli@3.13.1                                <-- here is the problem
│ ├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2
│ ├─┬ @expo/config@7.0.3
│ │ └── @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
│ └─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@5.0.7
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
└─┬ expo@48.0.17
  ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.7.1
  │ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
  └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2
```

I uninstalled `eas-cli` via 'yarn remove eas-cli' and run ' npx expo-doctor' again
This time it passed

```
❯ npx expo-doctor
[app.config.js] config.name: capmon-mobile
✔ Validating global prerequisites versions passed
✔ Checking for incompatible packages passed
✔ Checking for conflicting global packages in project passed
✔ Verifying prebuild support package versions are compatible passed
✔ Checking dependency versions for compatibility with the installed Expo SDK passed
✔ Validating Expo Config passed
✔ Checking package.json for common issues passed

Didn't find any issues with the project!
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

Add Native Folders (ios and android) to .gitignore and then run this command:

- git rm -r --cached ios
- git rm -r --cached android
- git commit -m "Remove ios and android folders from version control"

This will remove the folders from version control, but you will still have them locally for the project to work properly.